# Know if an enum is using on an entity - JPQL

Tags: jpql

I have an entity named Interview. This entity has an attribute called interviewType. My interview Type is an enum (phoneInterview and presentialInterview). I just make a presential interview, if a phone interview is already made. There is any chance to make a named query to know if a phoneInterview was used or not?

Answer (score 1):

Jpa deals correctly with enum types :

```
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private InterviewTypeEnum interviewType;
```

Then `select i from Interview i where i.interviewType = :type` with `setParameter("type", InterviewTypeEnum.phoneInterview)` will work.